# Jquery Complex wrap around uncontained group of items

Tags: javascript, jquery, wrapall

I'm trying to take group of headers and lists, and contain them individually so I can style them. ie:

```html
<h2>Title 1</h2>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
<h2>Title 2</h2>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

I attempted this by using `.before()` and `.after` to add a `div` before the `h2` tag, and close it after each `ul` however I found out that jquery cleans and closes the tag automatically. So I'm guessing I need to use `wrap()` just not sure how to group the title and list together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
$('h2').each(function(){
   var self = $(this);
   self.add( self.next() ).wrapAll('<div/>');
});
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/e4f9h/

Comment: You could make it a bit shorter and get rid of `self`: `$(this).next().andSelf().wrapAll('<div/>')`

Comment: @elclanrs, very nice... (*i think i must have never used it before.. although i have read about it.. thanks for the heads up..*)

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a jQuery collection that contains both elements. For this you would select the h2 elements. You than would need to find the [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) element that is a ul. After you get both of them linked, you would [`wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) with your containing div.

```
$("h2").each( function(){
   var h2 = $(this);
   h2.add(h2.next("ul")).wrapAll('<div class="madWrapper"></div>');             
});​​​​​​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FPL2u/)